# Three Js две синхронных анимации

Tags: javascript, анимация, three.js

Мне нужно, чтобы две анимации проигрывались синхронно. Имеется анимация `legs_run`, `legs_idle` и анимация `torso_weapon1`, `torso_weapon`2. Когда игрок держит первое оружие, для верхней части тела проигрывается анимация `torso_weapon1` но у ног проигрывается анимация иногда бега иногда ожидания. Как я могу комбинировать эти анимации одновременно и независимо друг от друга?